# how to print HTML string in C# using dialogue?

Tags: c#, html, string

I have a string in C# that is formatted in HTML. I want to print it on the printer using dialogue. without any distortion in CSS.

```
String htmlText = "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'> "+
            "<tr>"+
             "   <th align = 'right' width='80%'>Total</th>"+
              "  <th align = 'right'>25100.00</th>"+
           " </tr>"+
       " </table>";
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "distortion in CSS"?

Comment: that mean when i am saving that code into pdf using code ... 
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A5, 10f, 10f, 0f, 0f);
                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                    System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(billSavePath+slNo+".pdf", FileMode.Create);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);... the CSS prop. is not working prpoerly

Comment: where sbis string bulder and str = sb.tostring()